# AngularJs - get default HTML from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building angularJs directive, and I need to get element html before replacing it with template. For example:

```
<edit>Default title</edit>
```

My directive looks like:

```
.directive('edit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {},
        template: '<h1 ng-show="!edit_mode">{{variable.value}}</h1><input ng-show="edit_mode" ng-model="variable.value" />',
        link: function( scope, element ) {
            scope.edit_mode = false;
            scope.variable = {
                value: element.html() 
            }
            console.log( scope.variable );
        }
    }
});
```

But in console I see (same in webpage, of course)

```
Object {value: "<h1 ng-show="!edit_mode" class="ng-binding">{{variable.value}}</h1><input ng-show="edit_mode" ng-model="variable.value" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">"}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you plan on doing with the original nested HTML?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my post. Let's say I need to make that value editable, with default value provided in this tag..

Comment: Are you only ever editing a string value or could the inner html of the edit element be DOM? such as <edit><h1>Default title</hi></edit> and if it could be DOM would you want to see that full markup when editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiling order of execution is:

- Transclude elements
- Replacing the templates
- Run compile functions
- Creating scopes
- Instantiate controllers
- Run pre linking function
- Run post linking functions

At the time the linking function runs the original template is already replaced.
What you should do is save the original template before replacing it with a new one:

```
app.directive('edit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {},
    template: function(tElm, tAttrs) {
      tAttrs.value = tElm.html();
      return '<h1 ng-show="!edit_mode">{{variable.value}}</h1><input ng-show="edit_mode" ng-model="variable.value" />';
    },
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
      scope.edit_mode = true;
      scope.variable = {
        value: attrs.value
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like

```
<edit data="Default title">Default title</edit>

.directive('edit', function() {
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      data: "@"
    },
    template: '<h1>{{variable.value}}</h1',
    link: function( scope, element) {
        scope.variable = {
            value: scope.data
        }

        console.log( scope.variable );
    }
}
```

Here is live example http://plnkr.co/edit/8XphUri8PBMAHKNlfFMu?p=preview

Comment: Your answer is misleading as the values being displayed is not the inner HTML of the edit element but the data attribute on the edit attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already know how to get value from attributes.. But I don't want to repeat value in two places..